# windows phone 8 cordova external link open

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova, whitelist

`I am getting Whitelist exception: Stopping browser from navigating to` URL error in windows phone 8 with cordova 2.4 please suggest.

I added the URL in `config.xml`

```
<access origin="http://google.com" />
```

still giveing me the above error.

Comment: Are you testing it with `google.com` or `www.google.com`?

Comment: @JamieStarke yes i tried with both google.com and ww.google.com but getting the same error.